# How to get current thread's stack size via C API on Mac OS X? (no Cocoa or carbon)

Tags: c, macos, api, memory-management

In Unix, there's `getrusage` function to get the resource status. It is in Mac OS X too, but it does not work. There's pre-implemented API on Cocoa(I don't know about Carbon),

```
-[NSthread stackSize]
```

but I have to implement it with only C API.

What's the equivalent C API with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this *before* creating the thread, by initializing a `pthread_attr_t` object and calling `pthread_attr_getstacksize` on it. If you know the current thread was created with the default attributes, you could probably defer the test until later, but it sounds like a bad idea.

With that said, I think testing the default is rather useless anyway. If you know you need a large stack, explicitly set a large stack size before creating the thread. If you know you only need a small stack, explicitly set that and enjoy the memory savings. I would recommend not going any lower than 32k unless you know you won't be using any library functions or recursion (in which case 4k is probably fine), nor any larger than 256k unless you intend to do some deep recursion. A rough estimate I'd use for getting a safe stack size for recursion is:

```
levels_of_recursion * (128 + total_size_of_locals) + (using_lib ? 32768 : 4096)
```

Comment: Where does the 128 come from?

Comment: A safe upper bound for the amount of additional overhead for call frames. In reality it's probably something like 16-32 as long as you counted arguments in the size of locals, but it could be larger if you have a lot of complicated expressions that the compiler generates temporaries for.